# Paypal not able to process the payment using sandbox

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

right now I have to integrate a paypal payment and I face a problem when I'm using sandbox account.

So I prepare the PayPal payment using my Nodejs server then redirect the user (using sandbox) to finish the process but when I click on pay or continue I see this message:

> We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at
> this time. Please go back to merchant and try using a different
> payment method.

and I have in my URL:

> genericError?code=UEFZTUVOVF9ERU5JRUQ%3D

and this is my server code:

```
app.get('/pay', (req,res)=>{
    console.log('payement');
    var create_payment_json = {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://return.url",
            "cancel_url": "http://cancel.url"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": [{
                    "name": "item",
                    "sku": "item",
                    "price": "100",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": 1
                }]
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "100"
            },
            "description": "This is the payment description."
        }]
    };
    
    
    paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log("Create Payment Response");
            console.log(payment);
            for (var index = 0; index < payment.links.length; index++) {
                //Redirect user to this endpoint for redirect url
                if (payment.links[index].rel === 'approval_url') {
                    res.redirect(payment.links[index].href);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[image: U can here see the payment page.]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the deprecated v1/payments API or PayPal-Node-SDK? Don't do that. Use the current v2/checkout/orders or Checkout-NodeJS-SDK.

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

As for your generic error issue, try [creating a new sandbox Business account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F) for **another country such as the US** for your sandbox testing.  Then [create a REST App](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) for that new sandbox account, and use that app's sandbox Client ID and secret.

Comment: How can I get or find the clientId and secret code for the sandbox business account? when I review the account details I can only find the pw and the email and accountId.

Comment: Create a rest app for that SB Business account, in My Apps & Credentials... https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

Comment: ah I already have one, and I have test it but same problem here, Just a qst when U said " try creating a new sandbox Business account" U mean I have create it using sandbox account under dashboard or new dashboard account? because I have generate a sandbox busniss account but still the same problem (I'm from tunisia and here this is no paypal)

Comment: Create a US sandbox Business account.  Create a REST app that uses that sandbox business account.

Comment: As U can see here https://i.ibb.co/vDz9wzX/Capture.png when I create a sandbox US business account I can't find any REST app credentials just SOAP

Comment: Apparently you can't find it even when I mention the My Apps & Credentials page and provide a direct link to it... https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

Comment: ah! Sorry I didn't know that the Rest app account can be changed from the same page